# How to reuse a single random() instance in python

Tags: python, random

On the *jvm* (scala, java, kotlin, jruby etc) the following results in a single variable that is consulted repeatedly for new random values:

```
IntStream.range(0,10).forEach( __ -> System.out.println(rand.nextFloat()));
```

Is there an equivalent to *next[Float|Double|Int]* in python?  If not what happens under the hood when invoking

```
import random
for i in range(10):
   print(str(random.random()))
```

Is the `random` library itself holding on to a single *random* reference?  If not then how to ensure we avoid duplicates say by running many iterations within a few microseconds of each other?  I assume the system clock gets involved in the random number generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `random` library is holding onto a single instance of a pseudorandom generator. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a
> hidden instance of the random.Random class. You can instantiate your
> own instances of Random to get generators that don’t share state.

Yes, the system clock is used to seed the RNG, unless the operating system offers something better:

> If a is omitted or None, the current system time is used. If
> randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are used
> instead of the system time (see the os.urandom() function for details
> on availability).

Comment: Thanks for that info on the system clock and the potential use of the current system time. Several good answers: I will have to choose one of them.

Answer (score 1):

From the source,

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create one instance, seeded from current time, and export its methods
# as module-level functions.  The functions share state across all uses
# (both in the user's code and in the Python libraries), but that's fine
# for most programs and is easier for the casual user than making them
# instantiate their own Random() instance.

_inst = Random()
seed = _inst.seed
random = _inst.random
```

so it creates one random instance.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/random.py

Comment: Thanks for the actual source code!  Several good answers: I will have to choose one of them.

Answer (score 1):

It happens that all the callables in the `random` module behave as functions, and one could code Python all life without knowing that in this specific case, unlike in other modules, these callables are aliases to a single instance of `random.Random()` .

So, in short "Is the random library itself holding on to a single random reference?". Yes, it is on the random module as `random._inst`, and at the final lines of the `random.py` module file, the methods on this instance are aliased as module-level callables (with a bunch of `randint = _inst.randint` statements).

One interesting tidbit of this design is that while `_inst` and the default callables are instances of `random.Random`, the random module also offers the `SystemRandom` class that uses the O.S. random number generator as source, and an instance of it can in most cases be used as a reliable random number generator with the high level methods, instead of having to rely on the raw bytes provided by `os.urandom()`

Comment: Thanks for the details including `SystemRandom`. Several good answers: I will have to choose one of them.

Comment: I am happy enough with the upvote - feel free to mark one of the others as correct. :-)